# Can not Resolve Method 'putExtras (java.lang.string, void)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, youtube-api

I need some help.

I created a button for a click that was redirected to a new Activity, then I did:

When I click the button I want it to trigger a new activity with the result of the fullscreen function for youtube videos:

```
Player.setFullscreen (true)
```

But it throws the following error in the putExtras function: Can not Resolve Method 'putExtras (java.lang.string, void)

can anybody help me?

My code:

```
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, final YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
        player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);


        fullScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TelaCheia.class);
                intent.putExtras("key",  player.setFullscreen(true))
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });
```

Thank you.

Comment: the return type of `player.setFullscreen(true)` is void ,you cant pass a void value as parameter to `putExtra`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). - `player.setFullscreen(true)` does not return any value which could be passed as parameter to `intent.putExtras()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `player.setFullscreen(true)` does not return anything (hence the void in the error).

[This link explains the setfullscreen method](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#setFullscreen(boolean)).

I suggest you put all the relevant `YoutubePlayer` code into your `TelaCheia` `activity` or handle your `player.setFullscreen(true)` in your current `activity`

*Edited after our conversation in the comment section*

Comment: Hello.
Expected result of the player.setfullscreen is to make the display of a preloaded video appear in full screen. Thank You!

Comment: If the video is preloaded you could just start the new activity and make the `player.setFullscreen(true)` call right? No need to pass it into the Intent extra's.

As a side note, why do you need to start a new `activity` for it?

Comment: Rubens thanks for the agility and help.

I agree with you, you do not have to start a new activity.
It would actually be more of a convenience.
Because APP has two screens, one initial and the other with a list of videos.
When the person watched a video that is on the second screen and the video ends the person has to press back to exit the full screen, but instead go back to the second screen and it back to the first, so wanted to create a new Activity so that the person clicked on the back it would return to the second screen.

Comment: Ruben, I'm a beginner on android.
When doing a new activity I put the command player.setFullscreen (true);
But the player function was not recognized, how can I reference the player function that is in another activity?

Would it be possible?

Comment: I think it is not done to do it this way. Is there any reason it should be preloaded before going to the next activity?

I think you should move your current player code to your new activity and process it in there.

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo, correct method is `Intent.putExtra()`, not `Intent.putExtras()`.

Change it to `intent.putExtra("key",  player.getFullscreen())`

Comment: Not the problem. As player.getFullscreen is not a method which should return anything.